# Subsonic Security Exception in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, subsonic

I changed the trust level for my application to "Full" but I'm still getting the following error in Windows 7.  I followed the steps for using subsonic, but it appears I'm missing something.

`Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
allowed by the security policy.  To
grant this application the required
permission please contact your system
administrator or change the
application's trust level in the
configuration file.`

`Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException:
Request for the permission of type
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission,
System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
failed.`

```
 Source Error: 

 Line 3403:                this.SetKeyValue(newKey);
 Line 3404:            }else{
 Line 3405:                _repo.Add(this,provider);
 Line 3406:            }
 Line 3407:            SetIsNew(false);

 Source File: C:\src\gillisonlab.osumc.edu\Apps\OhioS3\OhioS3\ActiveRecord.cs
 Line: 3405
```

Comment: Can you provide additional information? It looks the application is having trouble accessing your database. You may want to double check your connection string as well as make sure your user has access on the DB.

Comment: Is the trust level locked by the machine.config by the sys admin? I don't think you can override the system trust configuration at the web app level.

Comment: Does it work if you run VS.NET as Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on 64 bit Windows you must remember to make changes to both the 32 bit and 64 bit .NET Framework configuration files:

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config`
>   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting "Load User Profile" to true on the Advanced Settings for the application pool.

I'm not sure why this works exactly but I think it's more secure than setting it to run as the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing here with Subsonic 3 on Windows 7 64bit.  Setting full trust in web.config didn't help.  I did get past the error by changing the App pool identity account to an admin account.

Gerry

Comment: I've been beating myself up over this exact problem for the past two days. Changing the Application Pool's identity account to the admin account worked for me, too... but by "worked" have we left our machines... "unbelievably vulnerable"? I'll be following up with a question on ServerFault later today and will cross-link the two.